# Mixitup hide filters if no combinations are available

Tags: javascript, mixitup

I'm using the Mixitup Multifilter plugin for a filter system which uses around 12 combination fieldsets.
Because there are many options and multiple combinations will deliver no results, I would like to know if there's a possibility in Mixitup to disable the buttons which will deliver no results.

Or what would be the start of the beginning point in developing such a function?

My system has over 15 products and an example of the product looks like:

```
<div class="mix cut-1 cut-2 coldforming-2 coldforming-3 ziehen-3 forging-3 chain-1 chain-2   yield-3 yield-2   harden-3 welding-1 welding-2 toughness-1 toughness-2 temper-1 temper-2">
  <span>Einsatzstahl</spa>
</div>
```